# Questions involved shiny from R Studio

Tags: r, shiny

Please, I would like help with some issues involving shiny. The executable code is below:

**Executable script and shiny code**

```
library(shiny)
library(kableExtra)
library(ggplot2)

#database
df<-structure(list(Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9), Longitude = c(-49.6, -49.6, -49.6), Waste = c(526, 350, 526)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
coordinaties<-df[,1:2]

#cluster
d<-dist(df)
fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average")
clusters<-cutree(fit.average,k=2)
df$cluster<-clusters

###Tables
table1<- kable(df[order(df$cluster, as.numeric(df$Longitude)),c(1,2,3,4)], align = "c", row.names = FALSE) %>%
    kable_styling(full_width = FALSE) %>%
    column_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%
    collapse_rows(columns = 1:4, valign = "middle")

table2<- kable(df[order(df$cluster, as.numeric(df$Longitude)),c(2,1,4,3)], align = "c", row.names = FALSE) %>%
    kable_styling(full_width = FALSE) %>%
    column_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%
    collapse_rows(columns = 1:4, valign = "middle")

table3<- kable(df[order(df$cluster, as.numeric(df$Longitude)),c(3,2,4,1)], align = "c", row.names = FALSE) %>%
    kable_styling(full_width = FALSE) %>%
    column_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%
    collapse_rows(columns = 1:4, valign = "middle")

table4<- kable(df[order(df$cluster, as.numeric(df$Longitude)),c(4,3,1,2)], align = "c", row.names = FALSE) %>%
    kable_styling(full_width = FALSE) %>%
    column_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%
    collapse_rows(columns = 1:4, valign = "middle")

table5<- kable(df[order(df$cluster, as.numeric(df$Longitude)),c(3,4,1,2)], align = "c", row.names = FALSE) %>%
    kable_styling(full_width = FALSE) %>%
    column_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%
    collapse_rows(columns = 1:4, valign = "middle")

###Graphs
plot1<-ggplot(data=df,  aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude,  color=factor(clusters))) +  geom_point()

plot2<-ggplot(data=df,  aes(x=Latitude, y=Longitude,  color=factor(clusters))) +  geom_point()

plot3<-ggplot(data=coordinaties,  aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude,  color=factor(clusters))) +  geom_point()

plot4<-ggplot(data=coordinaties,  aes(x=Latitude, y=Longitude,  color=factor(clusters))) +  geom_point()


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel (title = h2 ("Clusters for agricultural properties")),

    sidebarLayout (
        sidebarPanel (
            h2 ("Cluster generation"),

            radioButtons ("filter1", h3 ("Potential biogas productions"),
                          choices = list ("Select all properties" = 1,
                                          "Exclude properties that produce less than L and more than S" = 2),
                          selected = 1),



            radioButtons ("filter2", h3 ("Coverage between clusters"),
                          choices = list ("Insert all clusters" = 1,
                                          "Exclude with mean less than L and greater than S" = 2),
                          selected = 1),
        ),

        mainPanel (
            uiOutput("table"),
            plotOutput("plot")
        )))
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    my_data <- eventReactive(input$filter1, {
        if (input$filter1 == 1) {
            my_table <- table1
            my_plot <- plot1
           } 
        return(list(table = my_table, plot = my_plot))
    })

    output$table <- renderUI(HTML(my_data()[["table"]]))

    output$plot <- renderPlot(my_data()[["plot"]])

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Questions:**

1 - The options "Select all properties and" insert all clusters "are selected together when executing shiny, so I would like to show in this case, tables 1 and 2, as well as graphs 1 and 2.

2 - When it is "Select all properties" and "Exclude with mean less than L and greater than s" I would like to show table 3 and graph 3.

Thanksss

Comment: Could you please shorten your code? There is a lot here that has nothing to do with shiny. That is, since your question is about showing/hiding *tables*, I'd think you could get rid of `factoextra`, `cutree`, or anything `aggregate` and instead provide very simple data (3x3?) that shows or not based on some selectors.

Comment: Your question 4 makes it sound like you are asking for suggestions on a generic mechanism to support multiple arbitrary layouts, is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Question 4 is basically when pressing button 2, I would like to create a new layout with some features that I will still develop, that is, it will be different from this layout that is now. It is possible?

Comment: Jovani, I know of no "elegant" way of doing that; as is, your plot/table are going to be a spaghetti code of if/else statements to just get the right thing in the right place, now it looks like you want to add another if/else condition. That is, `if (A && B) table1 else if (A && !B) table2 else if (!A && B) table3 else table4` for your "basic" requirements, now either add a surrounding `if (C) { if (A && B) ... } else { if (A && B) ... }` or `if (A && B && C) table 1 else if (A && B && !C) table2 ...`. Do you see where I'm going with that?

Comment: I understand what you said. I am grateful for sending me an alternative to my problem. I will try to fit your code with what I want to do. If I have questions, can I get in touch?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212176/discussion-between-r2evans-and-jovani-souza).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple layouts, I have two suggestions:

1. Use a `data.frame` with all possible combinations (of your multiple inputs/radio-buttons) with another column indicating which of the tables/plots to display.
2. Store your tables and plots within lists instead of individual variables. If you choose not to do this, then instead of having an index in the `$choice` column, you can include the variable name (e.g., `table1`), and use `get` to retrieve the specific variable.

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)
tables <- lapply(1:4, function(i) data.frame(x=10*i + 1:3, y=runif(3)))
plots <- lapply(tables, function(tb) ggplot(tb, aes(x, y)) + geom_line())
layouts <- expand.grid(rb1 = c("Aa", "Bb"), rb2 = c("Cc", "Dd"), rb3 = c("Ee", "Ff"),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
layouts$choice <- c(1:4, 4:1)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        radioButtons("rb1", "Choice 1", c("Aa", "Bb")),
        radioButtons("rb2", "Choice 2", c("Cc", "Dd"))
      ),
      mainPanel(
        fluidRow(
          actionButton("btn1", "Button Ee"),
          actionButton("btn2", "Button Ff")
        ),
        textInput("txt", "Selection"),
        tableOutput("tbl"),
        plotOutput("plt")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    btn <- reactiveVal("Ee")
    observeEvent(input$btn1, btn("Ee"))
    observeEvent(input$btn2, btn("Ff"))
    selection <- reactive({
      req(input$rb1, input$rb2)
      out <- with(layouts, choice[ rb1 == input$rb1 & rb2 == input$rb2 & rb3 == btn() ])
      updateTextInput(session, "txt", value = out)
      out
    })
    output$tbl <- renderTable({
      req(selection())
      tables[[ selection() ]]
    })
    output$plt <- renderPlot({
      req(selection())
      print(plots[[ selection() ]])
    })
  }
)
```

And the various layouts:

```r
layouts
#   rb1 rb2 rb3 choice
# 1  Aa  Cc  Ee      1
# 2  Bb  Cc  Ee      2
# 3  Aa  Dd  Ee      3
# 4  Bb  Dd  Ee      4
# 5  Aa  Cc  Ff      4
# 6  Bb  Cc  Ff      3
# 7  Aa  Dd  Ff      2
# 8  Bb  Dd  Ff      1
```

[image: shiny app]

Comment: Jovani, I updated it to use two radio buttons and two action buttons, to better align with your intended model. I spent no time (obviously) beautifying it, since that's aesthetics and CSS and tweaking, more than I think was needed to demonstrate the concept and layout mechanism. Hope it helps.

Comment: It sure helped r2evans, thanks!. Just one last question, how doadjust to leave table and figure side by side instead of one under the other?

Comment: That's a new question :-) ... change `tableOutput("tbl"),plotOutput("plt")` to `fluidRow(
          column(width = 3, tableOutput("tbl")),
          column(width = 9, plotOutput("plt"))
        )`. The widths are out of 12, play with it. (Using `column` within `fluidRow` allows it to wrap when the screen size is incompatible with side-by-side.)

Comment: Sure ... and your question about multiple layouts is completely distinct (as far as solutions go) from a question about side-by-side, and asking too many questions in one SO-question is discouraged. I think it's easy enough, though, I should have included it in the first answer. Glad it worked for you!

Comment: I'm not too familiar with leaflet, sorry.

Comment: Please r2evans, can you look the question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787785/insert-distance-between-coordinates-in-shiny  Thank you very much!